# How to print value of a register using spike?

Tags: riscv

I have an assembly code for RISCV machine. 
I have added an instruction to access floating point control and status register and store floating point flags in register a3. I want to print its value to demonstrate that flag gets set when floating point exception occurs.

I tried using spike. There is an instruction in spike(in debug mode) to print value of a register:

```
: reg 0 a3
```

to print value of a3.
But first i have to reach my desired point.
I do not know how will i be able to reach that point.

```
    .file   "learn_Assembly.c"
    .option nopic
    .text
    .comm   a,4,4
    .comm   b,4,4
    .align  1
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    addi    sp,sp,-32
    sd  s0,24(sp)
    addi    s0,sp,32
    lui a5,%hi(a)
    lui a4,%hi(.LC0)
    flw fa5,%lo(.LC0)(a4)
    fsw fa5,%lo(a)(a5)
    lui a5,%hi(b)
    lui a4,%hi(.LC1)
    flw fa5,%lo(.LC1)(a4)
    fsw fa5,%lo(b)(a5)
    lui a5,%hi(a)
    flw fa4,%lo(a)(a5)
    lui a5,%hi(b)
    flw fa5,%lo(b)(a5)
    fmul.s  fa5,fa4,fa5

    frflags a3

    fsw fa5,-20(s0)
    li  a5,0
    mv  a0,a5
    ld  s0,24(sp)
    addi    sp,sp,32
    jr  ra
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align  2
.LC0:
    .word   1082130432
    .align  2
.LC1:
    .word   1077936128
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.2.0"
```

The other option is to somehow write print it using assembly instruction which i am not sure how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the flow of your program , you could create **object dump** of your program from compiled **elf** .

To create **elf** :-

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc assmebly_code.s -o executable.elf
```

Then you could create the **object dump** by :-

```
 riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d executable.elf > executable.dump
```

*executable.dump* will contains the program flow like this :-

```
executable.elf:     file format elf64-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000100b0 <_start>:
   100b0:   00002197            auipc   gp,0x2
   100b4:   35018193            addi    gp,gp,848 # 12400 <__global_pointer$>



   100b8:   81818513            addi    a0,gp,-2024 # 11c18 <_edata>
   100bc:   85818613            addi    a2,gp,-1960 # 11c58 <_end>
   100c0:   8e09                    sub a2,a2,a0
   100c2:   4581                    li  a1,0
   100c4:   1e6000ef            jal ra,102aa <memset>
   100c8:   00000517            auipc   a0,0x0
   100cc:   13850513            addi    a0,a0,312 # 10200 <__libc_fini_array>
   100d0:   104000ef            jal ra,101d4 <atexit>
   100d4:   174000ef            jal ra,10248 <__libc_init_array>
   100d8:   4502                    lw  a0,0(sp)
   100da:   002c                    addi    a1,sp,8
   100dc:   4601                    li  a2,0
   100de:   0be000ef            jal ra,1019c <main>
   100e2:   0fe0006f            j   101e0 <exit>
   .......  ........            .................
   .......  ........            .................
   .......  ........            .................
```

Recognize the required **pc** with required  **a3** value .

then on spike use command **until** to run till that pc value :

```
: until pc 0 <*required pc*>
```

***Note*** : Your compiler and assembler names may vary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use until spike instruction to execute until a desired equality is reached:

```
: until pc 0 2020                   (stop when pc=2020)
```

As explain [here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim) (interactive debug).

Once value reached you can use reg to read value you want.

Comment: But how to know what what value is in pc at my desired location.

Comment: In other words, how can i reach there?